# non-browsable URLs?

Tags: apache, url

How can one make URL's on their site non-browsable?

Example:

http://mydomain.com/files/file1.txt

If a user hits it directly, don't allow it.

If I call it inside an href on MY site then it would work.

Would one url-rewrite t accomplish this?

or how?

Apache, CentOS 5.5

Comment: You can configure this via permissions in apache. Search for how.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `Referer` header.
Note that not all browsers send `Referer` headers, so you'll be completely locking out some users.
Also note that the `Referer` header is trivially spoofable.

Alternatively, and more securely, you can protect the files with a server-side script.
Change your links to point to a server-side script and include a randomly-generated one-time passcode in the querystring.
The server-side script should verify the one-time passcode (use a database), then send the file to the client.

Depending on your application, you can also use an ordinary password-based authentication system.  (if you have user accounts)

Comment: This is really really horrible advice. Do not ever do this if you want to actually restrict access, as anyone can set this to whatever they wish.

Comment: @Noon: I'm well aware of that.  See my second half.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm leaving the downvote in place; it's really just not good advice at all for the posed question. And your updated information is also bad. The typical approach is to actually do some authentication; which is trivial in any servers configuration.

Comment: @Noon: It sounds like he doesn't have any user accounts.

Comment: @SLaks: You can create an apache config to request a user (Which can be created exceptionally trivially).

Comment: @Noon: If there isn't an existing system of user accounts, that won't apply.

Comment: @SLaks: I think you are a reasonably intelligent guy, I will leave you to consider the situation as I've told you, and I Think you will agree that there is a resolution that is trivial and appropriate and better then what you suggest. Sorry, but I can't remove the downvote in good consience with the adovacy of what I consider to be 2 very poor recommendations. No offence intended. I leave you with it.

Comment: Upvoting because these are the only sane solutions if no account or session system is already in place. @NoonSilk the OP is not talking about authentication, it is likely there is none in place and none is desired. I think you are reacting a bit irrationally to approaches that, if you know their inherent weaknesses, are perfectly valid and viable

Comment: @Noon Silk I feel like you're attacking SLak's answer when he gives two decent suggestions. He even added the limitations in his answer which is a valid answer, and since the OP did not mention how secure or reliable the answer should be, I believe SLak's answer is perfectly fine. As the limitations are listed, OP can decide if he will go that route.

Comment: @Pekka: You are totally wrong, I'm sorry. @Samuel: On a public forum, I don't think it is appropriate recommend bad solutions; my comments to SLaks reflect that attitude. Even with limitations, they shouldn't be proposed. It's simple really.

Comment: @Noon you are basing your judgement on requirements that are not known. The way it looks like, all the OP wants to do is prevent hotlinking, something a referrer check is the household tool for